# Toggle class on specific area div

Tags: jquery, css

When scroll to top the `blue`-class gets added to `#div`, but when it goes back to bottom the `blue`-class is not removed.

> Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/5d922roc

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var os = $('#div1').offset().top;
  var ht = $('#div1').height();
  if(scroll > os + ht){
    $('#div2').addClass('blue');
  }
});
```

```css
body, html {
 height: 101%;
 margin: 0;
}

.div {
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 5px;
 height: 500px;
 border: solid 1px black;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.div.blue { 
  background-color: #15158F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div">
  Div 1
</div>

<div id="div2" class="div">
  Div 2
</div>

<div id="div3" class="div">
  Div 3
</div>
```

Comment: Add an else statement.  Remove the class in the else statement

Comment: It's not adding on hovering, there is a `scroll` method in your script which actually add `blue` class when `#div2` scroll to top.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from [Taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601390/toggle-class-on-specific-area-div#comment99778734_56601390) and [Hassan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601390/toggle-class-on-specific-area-div#comment99778873_56601390) comments; your `if` statement needs an `else` statement to complete the command of "if scrolled to top, add `blue` to `div2`. if not at top of page, remove `blue`".

Updated/modified JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var os = $('#div1').offset().top;
    var ht = $('#div1').height();
    if(scroll > os + ht){
        $('#div2').addClass('blue'); // at top = blue
    } else {
        $('#div2').removeClass('blue'); // not at top = no blue
    }
});
```